# Jupyter notebook & Anaconda won't run after reinstalling python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I have been using jupyter notebook. Recently i was trying to run python from cmd but it would say python not recognized. So, i uninstalled python and then reinstalled it. Now python runs in cmd but my jupyter notebook and anaconda won't run anymore. How can i fix this?

Comment: Please provide some more information on your environment.

Comment: though I reinstalled anaconda to fix my problem.

Comment: I was using jupyter notebook for my python programs. But i suppose cmd wasn't configured with the path to python interpreter So i wasn't able to use python from my cmd root. I then uninstalled python and reinstalled it using cmd. After thoat i was able to use python from my cmd root but jupyter notebook and anaconda won't even start now.

Comment: _After thoat i was able to use python from my cmd root but jupyter notebook and anaconda won't even start now._ Reinstalling didn't fix the issue?

Comment: Reinstalled and now it is Fixed!

Comment: Always when reporting this kind of issue, show us the conda version, python versions, pip version, and your OS/platform version (e.g. Win 10, MacOS 10.15.x). Also, as you learned, you can sometimes have multiple python versions installed on your path/ environment, so check your path, and do `which python`.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda fixed my problem. And this time i kept in mind to add anaconda to the path.